# Robot Framework and Xpath - selecting an element using conditionals

Tags: xpath, robotframework

newcomer here. I'm making a first venture into automation testing and the website I'm testing uses AngularJS to generate dynamic graphs and bar charts with ever changing data and div IDs. As I am not code-savvy, I am looking to put together a test script using Robot Framework and relative Xpaths. My knowledge of Xpath mostly stems from the W3 schools Xpath tutorials (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

Here is a basic skeleton of the part of page I'm currently testing:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="charts_and_graphs">
            <div class="bar_chart">
                <h1>Book Sales</h1>
                <div class="key_area"></div>
                <div class="bar_area">
                    <div class="bar">a1</div>
                    <div class="bar">a2</div>
                    <div class="bar">a3</div>
                </div>
                <h1>Pen Sales</h1>
                <div class="key_area"></div>
                <div class="bar_area">
                    <div class="bar">b1</div>
                    <div class="bar">b2</div>
                    <div class="bar">b3</div>
                </div>
                <h1>Bag Sales</h1>
                <div class="key_area"></div>
                <div class="bar_area">
                    <div class="bar">c1</div>
                    <div class="bar">c2</div>
                    <div class="bar">c3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have included ExtendedSelenium2Library as a library in my Robot script and so far my test case looks like this:

```
Click on the first bar of the Book Sales bar chart
    Click Element    xpath=//child::div[@class="bar_chart" and ./h1/text()="Book Sales"]//div[@class="bar" and 1]
```

Needless to say, my test case failed with the following error:

```
ValueError: Element locator 'xpath=//child::div[@class="bar_chart" and ./h1/text()="Book Sales"]//div[@class="bar" and 1]' did not match any elements.
```

Here's a breakdown of my Xpath and the logic I'm trying to follow:

**//child::div[@class="bar_chart" and ./h1/text()="Book Sales"]** should select any child nodes of a div whose class is **bar_chart** and who has a child **h1** node enclosing the string **Book Sales**.

Within that selection, **//div[@class="bar" and 1]'** aims to choose the **first** div node whose class is **bar**.

I would really appreciate any tips or pointers that can help me achieve my goal of automatically clicking on the first bar of the Book Sales graph without relying in id attributes (they change pretty EVERY time I refresh the page) and that will work even if the bar charts are moved around the page (the structure of the charts themselves is unlikely to change however the ordering of the charts might change or the entire charts_and_graphs div might move to the top/bottom of the page... Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added text content a1-3,b1-b3,c1-3 to the `div.bar` elements in your example for clarification. Can you tell us (in terms of this text content)  which of the `div.bar` elements you want to select?

Comment: I'm trying to select the a1 bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to explain what didn't work with your expression, and then give a sample that should do for the intended purpose.

The first path of your expression - **//child::div[@class="bar_chart" and ./h1/text()="Book Sales"]** - doesn't catch what you think it does.
It selects all elements, which have a direct descendent (a child) being div, with that class value, and having an h1 child themselves with the text. In other words, it selects the `<div class="bar_chart">`.

Now,  going down from it, `//div[@class="bar" and 1]` will select the div with the class value, and that's it. The `1` will not be the element's position you intended it to be - the `and` will make a logical connection, and `1` will always evaluate to true - i.e. it's unneeded.

I can't say why it failed with element not found, with the samples you've provided the xpath returns all div nodes with `class="bar"` (you can try yourself [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)).

Say the position condition is fixed to work - then the expression will still not return what you expect out of it, as by the second part, it will return the 1st div with class="bar". What if "Pen Sales" was before the "Book Sales"? Well, you'd get the first item there, though you are after the Book's one.

---

So let's start with that - get the div that's for the Book Sales:

```
//h1[text()="Bag Sales"]/following-sibling::div[@class="bar_area"][1]
```

This expression will get the `h1` with the target text, and then will select it's first follow-up `div` sibling. Now that we're positioned at the correct `div` encompassing the bars, getting the 1st child with class "bar" is easy:

```
/div[@class="bar"][1]
```

So the full expression is:

```
//h1[text()="Bag Sales"]/following-sibling::div[@class="bar_area"][1]/div[@class="bar"][1]
```

By the way, a major problem getting the correct xpath for this source is the structure - all target elements are in a flat layout, not hierarchically grouped (e.g. an `h1` and the `div` with class="bar_area" being grouped together in common div). I guess you don't have control over it, but if it was a hierarchical structure, it would be trivial to work with.

Comment: Thank you sir for your help! I also appreciate the link to the freeformatter tool, it's a welcome addition to my pathetically small range of debugging tools.